# macOS brew hangs on building Python@3.9 (3.9.1_7)

Tags: python-3.x, macos, malloc, freeze

When I try to upgrade python@3.9 on my brew installation, the installation formula hangs. I see it hangs at `[19/43] test_functools` but there are many "failed (env changed)" and a few malloc crashes before the hang. How can I fix this?

I ran `brew upgrade python@3.9 —verbose` and the end of the output was the following:

> Python build finished successfully! The necessary bits to build these
> optional modules were not found: ossaudiodev           spwd
> To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for
> the module's name.
>
> The following modules found by detect_modules() in setup.py, have been
> built by the Makefile instead, as configured by the Setup files:
> _abc                  atexit                pwd                 time
>
> running build_scripts
>
> creating build/scripts-3.9
>
> copying and adjusting
> /private/tmp/python-3.9-20210409-53277-1nw4z9j/Python-3.9.4/Tools/scripts/pydoc3
> -> build/scripts-3.9
>
> copying and adjusting
> /private/tmp/python-3.9-20210409-53277-1nw4z9j/Python-3.9.4/Tools/scripts/idle3
> -> build/scripts-3.9
>
> copying and adjusting
> /private/tmp/python-3.9-20210409-53277-1nw4z9j/Python-3.9.4/Tools/scripts/2to3
> -> build/scripts-3.9
>
> changing mode of build/scripts-3.9/pydoc3 from 644 to 755
>
> changing mode of build/scripts-3.9/idle3 from 644 to 755
>
> changing mode of build/scripts-3.9/2to3 from 644 to 755
>
> renaming build/scripts-3.9/pydoc3 to build/scripts-3.9/pydoc3.9
>
> renaming build/scripts-3.9/idle3 to build/scripts-3.9/idle3.9
>
> renaming build/scripts-3.9/2to3 to build/scripts-3.9/2to3-3.9
>
> touch profile-gen-stamp
>
> ## Next, run the profile task to generate the profile information.
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make
> run_profile_task
>
> LLVM_PROFILE_FILE="code-%p.profclangr"
> DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/private/tmp/python-3.9-20210409-53277-1nw4z9j/Python-3.9.4
> ./python -m test --pgo || true
>
> 0:00:00 load avg: 49.21 Run tests sequentially
>
> 0:00:00 load avg: 49.21 [ 1/43] test_array
>
> 0:00:09 load avg: 43.18 [ 2/43] test_base64
>
> 0:00:12 load avg: 43.18 [ 3/43] test_binascii -- test_base64 failed
> (env changed)
>
> 0:00:13 load avg: 43.18 [ 4/43] test_binop
>
> 0:00:13 load avg: 40.44 [ 5/43] test_bisect
>
> 0:00:14 load avg: 40.44 [ 6/43] test_bytes
>
> 0:00:41 load avg: 30.43 [ 7/43] test_bz2 -- test_bytes failed (env
> changed)
>
> 0:00:53 load avg: 27.29 [ 8/43] test_cmath
>
> 0:00:55 load avg: 26.46 [ 9/43] test_codecs
>
> 0:01:14 load avg: 22.72 [10/43] test_collections
>
> 0:01:23 load avg: 21.78 [11/43] test_complex
>
> 0:01:26 load avg: 21.64 [12/43] test_dataclasses
>
> 0:01:31 load avg: 21.59 [13/43] test_datetime
>
> 0:02:14 load avg: 16.20 [14/43] test_decimal -- test_datetime passed
> in 43.1 sec python(62860,0x7fffa14ec380) malloc: ***
> mach_vm_map(size=842105263157895168) failed (error code=3)
>
> *** error: can't allocate region
>
> *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug python(62860,0x7fffa14ec380) malloc: ***
> mach_vm_map(size=842105263157895168) failed (error code=3)
>
> *** error: can't allocate region
>
> *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>
> python(62860,0x7fffa14ec380) malloc: ***
> mach_vm_map(size=421052631578947584) failed (error code=3)
>
> *** error: can't allocate region
>
> *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>
> python(62860,0x7fffa14ec380) malloc: ***
> mach_vm_map(size=421052631578947584) failed (error code=3)
>
> *** error: can't allocate region
>
> *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>
> 0:03:22 load avg: 15.19 [15/43] test_difflib -- test_decimal passed in
> 1 min 7 sec
>
> 0:03:33 load avg: 14.72 [16/43] test_embed
>
> 0:04:35 load avg: 12.80 [17/43] test_float -- test_embed passed in 1
> min 1 sec
>
> 0:04:39 load avg: 13.13 [18/43] test_fstring
>
> 0:04:46 load avg: 12.96 [19/43] test_functools
>
> ^C
>
> One sec, cleaning up...
>
> ln -s ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/bin/2to3 2to3
>
> ln -s ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/bin/2to3-3.9 2to3-3.9
>
> ln -s ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/bin/easy_install-3.9
> easy_install-3.9
>
> ln -s ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/bin/idle3 idle3
>
> ln -s ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/bin/idle3.9 idle3.9
>
> ln -s ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/bin/pip3 pip3
>
> ln -s ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/bin/pip3.9 pip3.9
>
> ln -s ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/bin/pydoc3 pydoc3
>
> ln -s ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/bin/pydoc3.9 pydoc3.9
>
> ln -s ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/bin/python3 python3
>
> ln -s ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/bin/python3-config python3-config
>
> ln -s ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/bin/python3.9 python3.9
>
> ln -s ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/bin/python3.9-config
> python3.9-config
>
> ln -s ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/bin/wheel3 wheel3
>
> ln -s ../../../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/share/man/man1/python3.1
> python3.1
>
> ln -s ../../../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/share/man/man1/python3.9.1
> python3.9.1
>
> ln -s
> ../../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.9-embed.pc
> python-3.9-embed.pc
>
> ln -s ../../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.9.pc
> python-3.9.pc
>
> ln -s ../../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/lib/pkgconfig/python3-embed.pc
> python3-embed.pc
>
> ln -s ../../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/lib/pkgconfig/python3.pc
> python3.pc mkdir -p /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework
>
> ln -s
> ../../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers
> Headers
>
> ln -s
> ../../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Python
> Python
>
> ln -s
> ../../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Resources
> Resources mkdir -p /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
>
> ln -s
> ../../../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9
> 3.9
>
> ln -s
> ../../../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current
> Current

Comment: I have the same problem, it hangs at `0:01:52 load avg: 5.71 [19/43] test_functools`

Comment: @bomben Same failure point that I had. If I knew more about packaging, I think skipping tests would be OK. Then things could move forward.

Comment: Yes, I have the feeling python3.9 is installed okay. But since I am not sure I would like to remove it and install 3.8 instead. Deactivating this in the future would also be good. But it seems that people do recommend changing to MacPorts instead for High Sierra.

Comment: Currently trying this approach with `pyenv`: https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac